# C++ Vector of shared_ptr of child to vector of shared_ptr to base

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
class GameObjectTemplateModel : public DatabaseModel<GameObjectTemplate, WorldDatabaseConnection, GameObjectTemplateModel>
```

And I have this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DatabaseModel>>  ManyWhere(const std::string& column, const std::string& where);
```

and this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObjectTemplateModel>> LootableCollection;
```

Why I can not do:

```
LootableCollection = ManyWhere("test","test");
```

My question is how can I make the vector of child shared_ptrs to get it's data from vector of base shared ptr?

Is it good idea if I use `dynamic_cast` ?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I make the vector of child shared_ptrs to get it's data from vector of base shared ptr?

You need to have something that will convert each pointer in turn. In C++23 that can be a view like `std::ranges::to<std::vector>`.

```
LootableCollection = ManyWhere("test","test") | std::ranges::to<std::vector>;
```

Prior to that you could use the iterator assignment (with a helper variable)

```
auto collection = ManyWhere("test","test");
LootableCollection.assign(collection.begin(), collection.end());
```

> Is it good idea if I use dynamic_cast ?

No. Using a pointer gotten via `dynamic_cast` is undefined behaviour in almost all cases, and this isn't one of the exceptions.

The type `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObjectTemplateModel>>` is not related to the type `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DatabaseModel>>` at all, despite the types `GameObjectTemplateModel` and `DatabaseModel` being related.

Comment: The way I read the question the intended conversion is from `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>` to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>` and not the other way round. There is no conversion constructor allowing a conversion from `std::shared_ptr<Base>` to `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`, so `assign` shouldn't work here...

Comment: Actually it is related, take a look: `class GameObjectTemplateModel : public DatabaseModel<GameObjectTemplate, WorldDatabaseConnection, GameObjectTemplateModel>`

Comment: @Venelin Just because the objects contained in the vector are pointers to related classes doesn't mean the two vector classes are related.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that even though there may be a way of converting between element types of the vectors, this doesn't establish a relationship between the vector types and the assigment operators/constructors necessary for the assignment/initialization to work do not exist.

You need to provide your own conversion for this. Depending on whether you're sure the types of the elements are ok or not, you should be using [`std::static_pointer_cast` or `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) for the element conversions:

The following example uses `Base` as base class and `Derived` as derived class for simplicity and assumes all elements of the `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>` actually reference `Derived`s.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
};

template<class T, class U>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> ConvertSharedPointerVector(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<U>>&& from)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> to;
    to.reserve(from.size());

    for (auto& e : from)
    {
        to.emplace_back(std::static_pointer_cast<T>(std::move(e)));
    }

    return to;
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> Create()
{
    return { std::make_shared<Derived>(), std::make_shared<Derived>() };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> convertedVector = ConvertSharedPointerVector<Derived>(Create());
}
```

Note: You're likely better of avoiding this kind of conversion. You may be able to use templates for this.